# Seasoned Advice Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a moderator, would you be interested in having your own Seasoned Advice contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to friends, coworkers and family to promote our site.

Below is a mockup:

<sub>(click on image to see full res version)</sub>

[image: Seasoned Advice Moderator Cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a great idea, and I'd definitely take a few. I frequently go to cooking classes and end up telling a few people there about SA, but I get the impression that it likely goes out of their mind the second they leave. Handing out a couple of these could really be helpful.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't be opposed to giving them to users with more than a certain rep too. It would definitely be a convenient way to  spread word about the site.

Comment: @yossarian I'm doing the cards for moderators first. I'll be making generic site cards later, for users who want them to promote the site.

Answer (score 2):

If we wanted real name and user name on the card, should we do username as one of the contact lines?

Comment: in that case, I think you should put your real name as your.. real name. Then use the shortened user url as one of the contact lines. for example: seasonedadvice.com/u/1259

Answer (score 0):

OK, the cards are now available -- all current moderators were mailed a link to the form to customize the cards. Enjoy!